# Eclipse Wiping out my projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a student at Comp. Eng. and we have a lesson about mobile programming. So we are using eclipse and developing apps for android but i'm not able to try my chance. Because Eclipse wiping everything when i add the project from existing code. It says "Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one." I'm clicking to android manifest and it is empty. Looking from the explorer and file turned to 0 kb :( Clicking to .java files and same for all. What is wrong with my computer and my ide?

Comment: probably there is a virus on your computer!

Comment: I'm using nod32 and fully updated :/

Comment: try using in safemode.

Comment: it happened with me once..when all files of my project moved to 0 kb....it can be because of two reasons..either that project did not get copied properly..or your computer carrying a serious virus..